# C# dllimport throws SEHException when called by Process.Start

Tags: c#, .net, dll, process, seh

I have a 32 bit dll that I need to be called from a 64 bit .NET Core Application.

My method to do this is to create a 32bit console App that basically looks like this:

```
[DllImport("x.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
static extern int x(int var);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.log("I Started!");
    int y = x(0);
    //do something with y.
}
```

And then to call that from my 64 bit Core Application using `Process.Start("consoleapp.exe")`

When I run the consoleapp.exe file, it prints "I Started!" as expected, and the operation of x.dll also executes correctly.

However, when I call the consoleapp.exe from process.Start() I get an SEHException thrown after "I Started!" is printed to the output (i.e. when the DllImport part is hit).

Here is how I'm starting the process within my 64bit App

```
ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo("consoleapp.exe");
Process process = Process.Start(p);
process.WaitForExit();
```

I have already tried user impersonation and running the Process object as an administrator, and it isn't working.

The dll file, x.dll is definitely in the working directory of consoleapp.exe, as I have made the process do a console.writeline() on the working directory, and it matches where the x.dll file is located.

The SEHException error code is 0x80004005, which is E_FAIL "Unspecified Failure"

---

UPDATE: As requested, stack trace is:

```
  at Consoleapp.Consoleapp.x(int32 var)
  at Consoleapp.Consoleapp.Main(String[] args)
```

Not sure how that helps you. If you mean the stack trace of the External Exception, I can't work out how to access that (InnerException is null) - some kind of guide may be good to help me do that.

The message attached to exception is "External component has thrown an exception."

The x.dll file reads a file in a subdirectory under CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA. This variable is correct when I run program directly, and from web app - used console.log on `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData))`
The file contents are read to get database location and credentials to read from a particular database. If any part of that fails, the x.dll returns an error code, not an exception, and I have double checked this is the case by changing credentials in file, database name, record numbers, etc. and no SEHExceptions were thrown when run directly.

Comment: That's entirely too vague, at a minimum you have to give us the **exact** exception message and a stack trace   Writing an event handler for AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException so you get better diagnostics is never optional.  Ask whomever wrote the DLL to help you out.

Comment: Did you show the actual signature of your native method? Is the native dll your own dll and you could share the source or is it a third-party lib? 

It may also help to look at the [`ExternalException.ErrorCode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.externalexception.errorcode.aspx) property.

Btw, any particular reason that you are setting shell execute to true? That does not seem to be needed here.

Comment: @DirkVollmar - the SEHException error code is the same as the ExternalException.ErrorCode. ShellExecute is not needed here, no, taking out doesn't change behaviour, though

Comment: @HansPassant - I can't ask the persons who wrote the DLL to help - they have flat out refused to help in any respect, including compiling to 64bit (which would remove the need for this console app completely). The DLL is not publicly accessible, and no source code is available to me either.

Comment: Did you make sure that you set the correct working directory in your `ProcessStartInfo` (i.e. that the working directory is set to the same directory that you use when you start your console app interactively)?

Comment: Yes, the working directory is the same in both instances

Comment: Add a "Console.ReadLine()" to your Main method (after "It Started!") and, when it hits, attach the Visual Studio debugger in Mixed mode and set it to stop on all Win32 first chance exceptions.

Comment: Another suggestion: Write your 32-bit console app in C++ (use LoadLibrary to load "x.dll" and GetProcAddress to find the entry point of "x"). Debugging that will at least confirm whether .Net is to blame here. (Also, it will start faster and use less memory)

Comment: Not sure I understand - you want me to write a new console app in C++ and then call Process.Start() on that executable instead?

Comment: @binderbound Yes, exactly.

Comment: Can you write your own 32-bit DLL for testing? It doesn't have to do anything other than return a number. That way you can rule out whatever's in your target DLL as a source of the problem.

Comment: Have you tried to start your 32 console app from a 32bit app with `Process.Start`? Just to be sure it is a 32/64 bit problem.

Comment: Starting the 32 console app from 32 bit process.start - not done that. Writing 32 bit DLL is also a good idea.
I have decided to implement a windows service to do this job instead, and so far it has worked pretty well. If I get time I'll come back and try to sort out what's going on here, but I've already spent six days on it, and I've got a working solution, so I'm moving on

Answer (score 1):

Make it

```
public static extern x(int var);
```

and/or try to specify it as void

```
public static extern void x(int var);
```

Comment: Hi thomas - I didn't specify in original question, but the signature return type is int for the DLL, and I intend to do stuff with that int later